# Do I have to use a Backend when using Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, backbone.js

I want to develop a relatively simple application that calculates some value based on several inputs.  I dont want a backend, all the calculation can be done in the browser.

Im a little new to JavaScript and WebApps and I came across [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).

I really like the MVC design, however, they mention a backend a lot.  My question:

- Is a backend server absolutely required?
- Is a backend server optional but without one there isn't much point in backbone.
- Or will backbone will really help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Backend is not required.
2. Backbone can fully work without any backend if your application doesn't require one.
3. That depends on your application. If you want to retrieve value of some inputs and calculate a result then Backbone won't do that for you - it will help you structure your code. If you app is simple and don't need support for models, views and collections or routing, then there is no point in using Backbone. Hard to answer this question.

For example: Classic [todo](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/11/backbone-dot-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started/) example application doesn't use any backend.

Comment: Wow, I really love the example, it's the sort of thing I want.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Backbone.js implements `fetch()`, `save()`, `destroy()` etc. methods on models automatically performing appropriate AJAX requests and parsing response. So it has a strong *support* for backend via REST services, but it is optional.

You can still use models, views, routers and events without any server-side code. Just don't call REST methods (or override them at your wish).

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage for persistence (you'd have to implement this yourself or find it on the web, like [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html)) but if you don't even need that then you don't need to use any of the persistence methods in backbone.

Backbone is meant to help you structure a medium-large sized application (js-wise), so it doesn't become unmaintainable jQuery spaghetti. With short applications (js-wise) it's really an overkill unless you are trying to learn how backbone works.

Note with js-wise I mean the client side code, if you had a huge backend but the only js would be something that focuses some form, it would not even count as a short application (js-wise).

Comment: You don't have to [implement this yourself](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use backbone.js without a backend. However you obviously won't be able to store or retrieve data. Backbone may still be useful for keeping your code organized, however it really shines when you want to separate presentation logic from logic that manipulates your data, which is a goal of the MVC pattern. Generally your data will be stored on and retrieved from a backend.

If you want to play around with data persistence, try out [backlift.com](https://www.backlift.com). [disclosure, I work on [backlift.com](https://www.backlift.com)] We've tried to make it easy to get a backbone app up-and-running without having to setup a server or deal with compiling templates.