# Does backbone-relational need a backend?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, indexeddb, backbone-relational

Experimenting with backbone-relational; I'm using Indexeddb to store all my data, is it possible to use backbone-relational without a backend and just let it talk to Indexeddb?

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 1):

Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545350/do-i-have-to-use-a-backend-when-using-backbone-js) to a similar question.

TL/DR: If you don't need to retrieve or store data on the server side there is no need for backend logic development.

> 1. Backend is not required.
> 2. Backbone can fully work without any backend if your application
>      doesn't require one.
> 3. That depends on your application. If you want to retrieve value of
>      some inputs and calculate a result then Backbone won't do that for
>      you - it will help you structure your code. If you app is simple and
>      don't need support for models, views and collections or routing,
>      then there is no point in using Backbone. Hard to answer this
>      question.